# How to calculate statistical power of R^2 in Python?

Tags: statistics

Is there any way to calculate the statistical power of an R^2 value in Python? I know you can do it for a t-test but I can't find anyway to do it for R^2.

Comment: R^2 can be computed from a various amount of libraries, which one are you referring to?

Comment: @Nauel I am specifically asking for the statistical power, i.e. 'the likelihood of a significance test detecting an effect when there actually is one'.